# Помощь в выборе игрового движка для разработки игры

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, unreal-engine-4

Какой из движков я предполагаю использовать:
**Unity3d**, **Unreal Engine 4** или **Godot Engine**.

Какова идея игры:
Игра платформер бродилка с видом с боку по мотивам рассказов об объекте SCP-087 - Лестница. Игра может быть 3d или 2d.

Я знаю что все эти движки способны сделать эту игру. Мне просто нужны рекомендации от тех кто работал с одним из них или даже несколькими.

Comment: Платформер - самое простое что может быть, любой движок с этим справится. Какой лучше - это не решаемый спор. Я знаю unity и могу советовать только его. У них даже есть какой то туториал по платформерам https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/creating-basic-platformer-game

Comment: На самом то деле я знаю что все они справятся с этой задачей. Мне просто было интересно увидеть ответы от тех кто знаком с одним из этих движков. Ну и естественно увидеть рекомендации по выбору из этих же движков.

Comment: Monogame это фреймворк, предоставляющий минимальные возможности, а не движок в его полноценном понимании. Если не хотите все вручную хардкодить через код и самому писать физику, лучше его сразу вычеркните.

Comment: Согласен про MonoGame. Но он весьма хороший игровой фреймворк.

Comment: Удалил из текста вопроса ТС(с):  Вопрос решён. Больше ответа не нужно. Только зря потратил чужое время на получения ответа на свой вопрос. Но спасибо @andrew за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если такой вопрос возник в принципе, то уровень знаний невысок.

Мой ответ: лучший в данном случае тот движок,

- который ты знаешь;
- который работает с языком который ты знаешь;
- у которого большое комьюнити и кто-то что-то может подсказать;
- и который при этом бесплатный;

Всё остальное - не важно.

Comment: `Если такой вопрос возник в принциме, то уровень знаний невысок.`

Уровня знаний достаточно, чтобы разработать игру на любом из движков в списке выше.

C++ знаю на хорошем уровне, 3 года его учил.
C# знаю намного выше чем C++, изучал его еще с 16 лет. Мне сейчас 23.

Comment: Python знаю достаточно хорошо. Хоть в Godot Engine используется не Python, а язык с Python-подобным синтаксисом. Да и язык GDScript очень легкий в изучении.

В общем те языки что используются в этих 3-х движках я знаю. Но какой точно выбрать я пока не знаю.

Comment: Пожалуй я выбрал для себя движок. Unity вполне подходит.